# jQuery DataTable with huge data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am using jQuery Data Table plugin where I select a lot of data from db.
Because of the huge amount of data is loading in table, it takes some time to finish initializing and storing data. And during this process my table looks ugly. So I guess I need To hide table before it finishes initializing and show some buffer gif. And after it finishes to load all data from DB only then show table.

Please help me do that, or suggest better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
    // Show ajax image throbber
    $('#loadingImage').show();

    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {

               // Hide throbber once table draw is complete
               $('#loadingImage').hide();
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.
I have a div containing the loader gif image.
this div overlays whole page to hide table during init.
But the page is freezing from time to time during init and makes my gif image not to rotate smoothly ) if you know what I mean. Can we fix that too?

Comment: How you are loading data. Using sajaxsource and fnServerData?

Comment: I have a mysql select in query.php which is included in my index.php (where my table is)
and then I am putting data in rows like this:

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
     
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['first']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['second']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['third']?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>

I am newbie. and if this is silly help me make it better please )